# How to make a function with two strings as arguments

Tags: vbscript, computer-science

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have tested the code by input and output and it functions as desired no pun intended. :'P

I'm just not setting up this function correctly and I believe it's because my arguments happen to be desirably a string. Where if done correctly "CD" will be inserted into the middle of "ABEF". So, how do I go about doing this?

Thanks!

```
insertstr(ABEF, CD)

Function insertstr(string1, string2)
nostrmsg = "No string"
fullng = len(string1)
half = len(string1)/2
if half>0 then hfstr1 = mid(string1, 1, half)
str2lng = len(string2)
if str2lng>0 then paste = hfstr1+string2
lshalf = mid(string1, half+1, fullng)
if str2lng+half=str2lng+half then insert = paste+lshalf
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with the knowledge that a functions returns a value, a tentative specification of what the function should do, and a basic testing skeleton:

```
Option Explicit

' returns the string build by inserting m(iddle) into f(ull) at half position
Function insertInto(f, m)
  insertInto = "?"
End Function

Dim t, r
For Each t In Array( _
   Array("ABEF", "CD", "ABCDEF") _
)
   r = insertInto(t(0), t(1))
   WScript.Echo t(0), t(1), r, CStr(r = t(2))
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 26873276.vbs
ABEF CD ? False
```

Then learn about [Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk3xcs8k%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), [Mid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), [Len](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42byt104%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), and [\ (integer division)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzydt0tx%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

At last, re-write insertInto() so that the result starts with

```
cscript 26873276.vbs
ABEF CD ABCDEF True
```